# Seaborn swarmplot of grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby

When I have a dataframe likes this here:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":[random.random() for i in range(100)], "Cluster":[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(100)]})
```

I can easily plot the clusters with seaborn as boxplots:

```
sns.boxplot(df["Data"], groupby=df["Cluster"])
```

Which gives me something like this:
[image]

Unfortunately seaborn swarmplot does not have a groupby keyword. So, how can I convinently plot this dataframe as grouped swarmplots? I want the same figure as shown only with swarmplots instead of boxplots. I played around with the groupby object itself:

```
df.groupby(by="Cluster")
```

So far I could not convince seaborn to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to `groupby` - you simply want to specify the cluster as your x value and the data as your y:

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x="Cluster", y="Data")
```

Gives you:

[image: swarm plot in seaborn]

However, if you had a further category that you wanted to colour by, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":[random.random() for _ in range(100)],
                   "Cluster":[random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(100)],
                   "Category": [random.choice(("A", "B")) for _ in range(100)]})
```

You can then use the `hue` argument like so:

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x="Cluster", y="Data", hue="Category")
```

and get:

[image: swarm plot with categories]

Comment: Well, this was easier than expected.